# Required attribute for a dropdown does not work

Tags: html

I have a html form which has a dropdown consisting of a few values. If the user does not select an option and moves to the next field, I need to give an error message. I have used the required attribute but it does not fire in Chrome and Firefox.

This is my code :

```
<select name="gender" id="gender" style="max-width:100%"  required>
       <option value="">Select Gender</option>
       <option value="Male">Male</option>
       <option value="Female">Female</option>
       <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

The required attribute does not work on Chrome and Firefox. A JavaScript solution would also be good. At the time of submitting the data I am checking for empty fields but I would like to display an error message if the user does not select a value from the dropdown and moves to the next field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `onfocusout` option on your `select` paired with some Javascript.

**HTML**

```
<select name="gender" id="gender" onfocusout="check()" style="max-width:100%"  required>
       <option value="">Select Gender</option>
       <option value="Male">Male</option>
       <option value="Female">Female</option>
       <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function check(){
var x = document.getElementById("gender").selectedOptions[0].label;

  if(x == "Select Gender"){
    alert("Please select an option.");
   }
}
```

**CodePen.io**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XQxQgw

There's undoubtedly a more efficient way of doing this and you would need to tweak the JS to check if all fields have been completed etc. but that's my two cents in a pinch!

Comment: Mr. Slug this worked perfectly. Just a couple of things, 1) how do I make it generic as I have other dropdowns? 2) How do I get the focus to remain the same field after the error message?

Comment: In terms of making it generic, you could use some jquery to add an event listener for the "onblur" event on your selects, but as mentioned in the answer below a form tag surrounding all of the selects would provide a "Please enter a value" notification as well as focus on the element in question. If that isn't something you want to try, play around with focus(), this will refocus on the element you call it on i.e. object.focus()

Comment: Thank you Mr. Slug.

Answer (score 4):

Use below code, not need any script, use **form** tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
<select required>
  <option value="">None</option>
  <option value="demo">demo</option>
  <option value="demo1">demo1</option>
  <option value="demo2">demo2</option>
  <option value="demo3">demo3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not have a submit button after the dropdown. There is a field next to the dropdown.  If the user does not select an option from the dropdown and moves to the next field there should be an error message.

Comment: make next fiedl to submit button.

Comment: Didn't understand your last comment.